# how to show databases in mysql using regexp

Tags: mysql, regex, database

In Mysql db, I have many databases, like

```
msgnotify_0,msgnotify_1....msgnotify_20,msgnotify_21.......msgnotify_98,msgnotify_99.
```

I want to only get database name including

```
msgnotify_0,msgnotify_1....msgnotify_20,msgnotify_21,msgnotify_48,msgnotify_49
```

**not including** 
`msgnotify_50,msgnotify_51.....msgnotify_98,msgnotify_99.`

Execute `show databases` will give me all the databases in the db,

Execute `show databases like 'msgnotify_%'` also give me all the databases.

how can I get the only previous 50 database names?

**using regexp? how?**

Answer (score 3):

All the DB informations are saved in a table called `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` so you could use that to get whatever you want something as

```
select 
SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA 
where 
substring_index(SCHEMA_NAME,'_',-1) < 50 
and SCHEMA_NAME like 'msgnotify_%';
```

Here is a test case

```
mysql> show databases ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| db_1               |
| db_2               |
| db_49              |
| db_50              |
| db_51              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+

mysql> select SCHEMA_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA 
where substring_index(SCHEMA_NAME,'_',-1) < 50
and SCHEMA_NAME like 'db_%';
+-------------+
| SCHEMA_NAME |
+-------------+
| db_1        |
| db_2        |
| db_49       |
+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In some of the environments the access for the information_schema will be restricted in those case you can write your query like this

```
SHOW DATABASES where substring_index(`database`,'_',-1) < 50
and `database` like 'msgnotify_%';
```

Try this, this will work.